# Discrete mathematics - logical equivalence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm asked to find a logical expression that is equivalent to the one listed in the question below, but I'm stumped as to what steps I would take next. If someone could show me step by step how to solve them and what rules would be used, I would really appreciate it.

1. Using only the NOT and the AND operators, find an expression that is equivalent to ¬(a ∧ ¬b)↔

The furthest I got is (¬a∨b)↔c by using De Morgan's law, but I don't know how I can simplify it further than that. Someone told me the final answer is b ↔ c but I have no idea how they got there or if it's even correct?

Comment: In part A) $b\leftrightarrow c$ is incorrect.  What if $a$ and $b$ are flase and $c$ is true?

Comment: You want to remember that the biconditional can be broken up into two conditional statements with the AND: p $\leftrightarrow$ q $\equiv$ (p $\rightarrow$q) $\land$ (q $\rightarrow$ p). Then you use the implication equivalence and keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A \leftrightarrow B$ is logically equivalent to $(\lnot A \lor B) \land (\lnot B \lor A)$, we have:
\begin{align}
\lnot (a \land \lnot b) \leftrightarrow c &\equiv ( \lnot \lnot (a \land \lnot b) \lor c) \land (\lnot c \lor \lnot (a \land \lnot b)) \\
&\equiv ((a \land \lnot b) \lor c) \land (\lnot c \lor \lnot (a \land \lnot b)) \\
&\equiv ((a \land \lnot b) \lor c) \land \lnot (c \land  a \land \lnot b) \\
&\equiv ((a \lor c) \land (\lnot b \lor c)) \land \lnot (c \land  a \land \lnot b) \\
&\equiv (\lnot (\lnot a \land \lnot c) \land \lnot (\lnot \lnot b \land \lnot c)) \land \lnot (c \land  a \land \lnot b) \\
&\equiv (\lnot (\lnot a \land \lnot c) \land \lnot (b \land \lnot c)) \land \lnot (c \land  a \land \lnot b) \\
\end{align}